# Synonims in SQL Server 2008 R2 FTS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search, synonyms

The Search feature on my website is based on SQL Server's Full Text Search (I insert everything relevant to a single table and this table is in the FTS Catalog).

We don't have money to buy a thesaurus but we do want the search to include other similar words too. The Words API provides synonyms for each word sent to it. From tests I've done it's usually 3 synonyms for a word (even if it's more, 3 is enough at this stage).

We were thinking of the following:

1. Send the text to SQL to get tokens
2. Call words API on each token to get synonyms
3. Concatenate synonyms to the string
4. Query using SQL using FREETEXT
5. Highlight results using a merged list (tokens + synonyms)

Will that approach hold water? Has anyone implemented something similar before? Is it better to replace the tokens with the synonyms and query SQL server separately the merge the results?

Comment: I wouldn't do the weird string concatenation thing, why not just extend your thesaurus[?](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345187(v=sql.105).aspx)  You could do something with a mix of FOR XML and SSIS pretty easily.

Comment: hi @wBob would that happen on the fly? can I pass a thesaurus to the FREETEXT query?

Comment: You can't.  You need to work through [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345187(v=sql.105).aspx) and [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142491(v=sql.105).aspx#initial_thesaurus_files) and create a process to update your thesaurus dynamically.